# How can i justifyContent only on specific sizes in react material ui?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, material-ui

I have a grid layout in react material UI.

I want on big sizes that content to be justified in the center but on small to be the default one flex-start.

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={2}>
                    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
                    <FormControlLabel
                            control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={checkbox}
                                    onChange={(e) => onCheckBoxChange(e)}
                                    name="checkedB"
                                    color="primary"
                                    className={classes.inputFullWidth}
                                />
                            }
                            label="Search by date ?"
                        />
                    </Box>
                    
                    </Grid>
```

The problem is that on their documentation i didn't find such an example for that

https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/#justify-content

In bootstrap we have something like

```
justify-content-md="center"
```

which means only on md > breakpoints the content will be justified in center.

How can i do this with react material ui ?

Answer (score 4):

Try passing it in an object:

```
   <Box display="flex" justifyContent={{lg: "center", sm: "flex-start"}}>
```

worked in mui v5

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Grid item xs={11} md={6}
                    container
                    justifyContent={{xs:"start",md:"center"}}>...</Grid>
```

Change/add the breakpoints as you need